# Calculate total number of records dynamically on Firebase server side instead downloading the whole database

Tags: firebase, emberfire

I found solutions for this problem only with snapshot, which downloads the whole database. It would be great to send a request to Firebase server which would respond the total number of records. Downloading the whole database is not really efficient. Any idea?

Related questions. (Most suggest watching `value` event, and checking size of the downloaded records... not efficient.)

[Firebase better way of getting total number of records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461937/firebase-better-way-of-getting-total-number-of-records)

[Total number of records in Firebase (when am I done counting?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618032/total-number-of-records-in-firebase-when-am-i-done-counting)

[Firebase - Count online users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982215/firebase-count-online-users)

Comment: There is one more recent [post on this](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/firebase-talk/14ajy2t3nt/firebase-child-count-with-good-performance), looks like they only provide API to download object keys instead of all objects. But there is no true server-side count

Answer (score 1):

You can try `?shallow=true` in GET request to retrieve total set of keys. Still downloading all the keys but limit the depth, hence much faster than watching `value`.

[Docs on shallow parameter](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-param-shallow)

Comment: Thanks. This is one of the partial solution... but it could be still huge payload for a simple number... let say, you have a 50.000 records in a table... already a quite big... Probably while Firebase doesn't implement this feature, Firebase is a little bit limited...

Comment: Hope this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148803/in-firebase-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-number-of-children-of-a-node-without-load/23132570#23132570